# GROUP BY Month, Display Month Name in SELECT List

Tags: t-sql, group-by, sql-server-2014

I am trying to group by month to separate my result set into monthly breakdowns, but I want to display the month name instead of the month number.

```
SELECT  
    DATEPART(MONTH, R.received_date) AS [Month],
    --DATENAME( MONTH, DATEPART( MONTH, R.received_date)) AS [Month] ,
    o.name AS [CountyName] ,
    rsc.description AS [Filing],
    COUNT(*) AS [Total] 
FROM    dbo.requests AS [r]
    INNER JOIN dbo.organizations AS [o] ON o.id = r.submitted_to_organiztion_id
    INNER JOIN dbo.request_status_codes AS [rsc] ON rsc.code = r.request_status_code
WHERE   r.submitted_to_organiztion_id < 68
    AND r.request_type_code = 1
    AND CAST(r.received_date AS DATE) >= '01/01/2016'
    AND CAST(r.received_date AS DATE) <= '06/30/2016'
    AND o.name = 'Alachua'
GROUP BY
    DATEPART(MONTH, R.received_date) ,
    --DATENAME( MONTH, DATEPART( MONTH, R.received_date)) ,
    o.name ,
    rsc.description;
```

And the results are expected below:

[image: GROUP BY Month]

But if I group by `DATENAME`, the results are not what I would expect from the query below:

```
SELECT  
    --DATEPART(MONTH, R.received_date) AS [Month],
    DATENAME( MONTH, DATEPART( MONTH, R.received_date)) AS [Month] ,
    o.name AS [CountyName] ,
    rsc.description AS [Filing],
    COUNT(*) AS [Total] 
FROM    dbo.requests AS [r]
    INNER JOIN dbo.organizations AS [o] ON o.id = r.submitted_to_organiztion_id
    INNER JOIN dbo.request_status_codes AS [rsc] ON rsc.code = r.request_status_code
WHERE   r.submitted_to_organiztion_id < 68
    AND r.request_type_code = 1
    AND CAST(r.received_date AS DATE) >= '01/01/2016'
    AND CAST(r.received_date AS DATE) <= '06/30/2016'
    AND o.name = 'Alachua'
GROUP BY
    --DATEPART(MONTH, R.received_date) ,
    DATENAME( MONTH, DATEPART( MONTH, R.received_date)) ,
    o.name ,
    rsc.description
ORDER BY
    [Month] ,
    CountyName ,
    Filing
```

when 6 months become grouped into one set - January:

[image: Wrong GROUPING]

What can I do to fix the query to display the first result set but with the month name instead of numeric value?

Thanks,

Comment: Why are you using `DATENAME(MONTH,DATEPART(....))`?, you should just use `DATENAME`: `DATENAME(MONTH,R.Received_Date)`

Comment: Thanks - figured it was something really simple.  As to why? Mainly because I haven't really used those functions before and I was trying to figure out how to use them.

Comment: As to explaining the behavior, your values of month (1-6) were being implicitly converted to dates which happen to all fall in January. Remember to be careful that your results don't contain more than a years worth of data or you'll need to group by year as well.